# result show/hide option value in dropdown2 after selecting item from checkbox1 and selecting item from dropdown1

Tags: javascript, php, html, jscript

i want to select a platform from checkbox1 and select the value from dropdown1 
as a result i want in dropdown2 it shows the value related to the platfrom

example : 
i check GI and 90 >> result in dropdown2 = 90 gi
if i check GI and xdo 190 >> result : 190 gi and 190 xdo

and would love that the value appear in the textbox 'lns'.

i tried some code but not working properly  :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{$('option[id^=sb]').hide();
$('input[id^=chk]').change(function(){
var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('chk','');
if($(this).is(':checked'))
$('#sb'+index).show();
else
$('#sb'+index).hide();
});   });   

$(function(){
$("#dropdown1").on("change",function(){
var levelClass = $('#dropdown1').find('option:selected').attr('class');
console.log(levelClass);
$('#dropdown2 option').each(function () {
var self = $(this);
if (self.hasClass(levelClass) || typeof(levelClass) == "undefined") {
self.show();
} else {
self.hide();
}});   });});

function chlink(){
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('dropdown2');
var a = dropdown2.options[dropdown1.selectedIndex].value;
var textbox = document.getElementById('lns');
 textbox.value = a; }
```

Any Help :)

Comment: here are a test : https://jsfiddle.net/cyrinez28/0o3b6gjk/42/

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chlink').on('click', function(){
        gatherValuesFromInputs();
    });
});

function gatherValuesFromInputs() {
    var result = '';
    $('.chk:checked').each(function(index){
     if(index == 0) {
         result += $('#dropdown').val() + " " + $(this).val();
        } else {
         result += ' and ' + $('#dropdown').val() + " " + $(this).val();
        }
    });
    $('#lns').val(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    <div style="float:right">
        <label for="option1">Xdo</label>
        <input class="chk" id="option1" type="checkbox" name="option1" value="xdo">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <label for="option2">GI</label>
        <input class="chk" id="option2" type="checkbox" name="option2" value="gi">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <label for="option3">PayF</label>
        <input class="chk" id="option3" type="checkbox" name="option3" value="PayF">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <label for="option4">HiP</label>
        <input class="chk" id="option3" type="checkbox" name="option4" value="HiP"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <option>choisissez un Pack</option>
    <option value="90"> LIEN 90  </option>
    <option value="190"> LIEN 190 </option>
</select>

<br><br>

<button class="chlink">Generer Lien</button>
<p><input name="lns" id="lns" type="text" /></p>
```

Comment: Hello @kamil thanks for your quick answer, i still need to check a checkbox option for example i check GI so in the dropdown2 i will have just the GI value options

Comment: @zzoccy i have adjusted my answer. Take a look and say if that helps you or not. I have removed `dropdown2` selecte because it wasn't necessary in this case. (or it is but i don't see usage)

Comment: Hello @ciekals11 thank you very much for your help, the issue is i need to have dropdown2 as it contains buttons. 
the scenario is to choose a checkbox GI for example and a number from dropdown1 (90) so i will get in dropdown2 ( 90 related to gi as a button to open a link)
later on i can generate the link in the textbox 
here what i tried but not working :(((
https://jsfiddle.net/cyrinez28/v1y2zmcq/10/

Answer (score 0):

You can store `checkboxes` value to an `array` and whenever a checkbox  is checked you can display values related to it and whenever a checkbox is unchecked hide the data related to it . Also i have made some changes in your html as well in script.Working example :

```js
var index = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide all contents
  $('option[id^=sb]').hide();

  $('input[id^=chk]').change(function() {

    //checking if checkbox is check put it in array 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      index.push($(this).attr('id').replace('chk_', ''));
    } else {
      //if uncheck remove the element from array
      if ((index1 = index.indexOf($(this).attr('id').replace('chk_', '')) !== -1)) {
        //hide all options related to that
        for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
          if (!$('#chk_' + index[i]).prop("checked")) {
            //hide option
            $('.' + index[i]).hide();

          }
        }
        //removing values from array
        index.splice($.inArray(index1, index), 1);
      }
    }

    //if check box is  checked show options related to that
    for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

      if ($('#chk_' + index[i]).prop("checked")) {

        $('.' + index[i]).show();

      }
    }


  });


  $(function() {

    $("#dropdown1").on("change", function() {
      var levelClass = $('#dropdown1').find('option:selected').attr('class');
      //looping through array 
      for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

        $('#dropdown2 option').each(function() {
          var self = $(this);


          if (self.val() == levelClass || typeof(levelClass) == "undefined" && self.hasClass(levelClass)) {
            //self.show();
            //showing option with class and value from array
            $('.' + levelClass + '.' + index[i]).show();
          } else {
            //self.hide();
            //hiding options
            $('.' + index[i]).not('.' + levelClass).hide();

          }

        });
      }
    });
  });
  //on click of Generer Lien button 
  $(".values").on("click", function() {
    //getting values of dropdown
    var v = $("#dropdown2").val();
    //assign to input 
    $("#lns").val(v);
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <div style="float:right">
      <label for="option1">Xdo </label>
      <input id="chk_xdo" type="checkbox" name="chb[]" value="xdo" autocomplete="on">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
      <label for="option2">GI</label>
      <input id="chk_gi" type="checkbox" name="chb[]" value="gi">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
      <label for="option3">PayF</label>
      <input id="chk_payf" type="checkbox" name="chb[]" value="PayF">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
      <label for="option4">HiP</label>
      <input id="chk_hip" type="checkbox" name="chb[]" value="HiP" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<br>

<select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1">
  <option value="">choisissez un Pack</option>
  <option class="490" value="490"> 490,00 </option>
  <option class="390" value="390"> 390,00 </option>
  <option class="290" value="290"> 290,00 </option>
  <option class="190" value="190"> 190,00 </option>
  <option class="90" value="90"> 90,00 </option>
</select>

<br>
<select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2">
  <option></option>
  <option style="color:#0bb6b6" class="90" value="90">LIEN 90</option>
  <option id="sb1" class=" xdo 90" value="xdo90">90 xdo</option>
  <option id="sb2" class=" gi 90" value="gi90">90 gi</option>
  <option id="sb3" class=" hip 90" value="hip90">90 hip</option>

  <option style="color:#0bb6b6" class="190" value="190">LIEN 190</option>
  <option id="sb1" class=" xdo 190" value="xdo190">190 xdo</option>
  <option id="sb2" class="gi 190" value="gi190">190 gi</option>
  <option id="sb3" class="hip 190" value="hip190">190 hi</option>

</select>
<br><br>


<button class="values">Generer Lien </button>
<p><input name="lns" id="lns" type="text" /></p>
```